# Oracle - Can this query be optimized?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the last Date of a set of rows. What is more performant: Query1 or Query2:

**Query1**

```
select *
from(
select column_date
from table1 a join table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where id= '1234'
order by column_date desc) c
where rownum=1
```

**Query2**

```
select column_date
from table1 a join table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where id= '1234'
order by column_date desc
```

and take the first row in backend.

Or maybe is there another way to take the first row in Oracle? I know that normally subselects are bad performant. That's why I am trying to remove the subselect.

I tried that but I am not getting the result expected:

```
select column_date
from table1 a join table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where id= '1234' and rownum=1
order by column_date desc
```

Comment: If you are on Oracle 12 then you can use that second query and add `fetch first 1 row only` to the end of it. Otherwise you have to subselect.

Comment: Why not simpler `select MIN(column_date)
from table1 a join table2 b on a.column1=b.column1
where id= '1234'`

Comment: You are right. Actually I need `select max(column_date)` and without `order by column_date desc`

Comment: Please qualify the columns when your query includes multiple tables. I'm talking about `id`.

Comment: Elaborating on Wernfried Domscheit's answer: Oracle allows you to select `max(column)` in a single `select` statement, even without a `group by` clause. The SQL Standard doesn't allow such things, but adding `group by null` has exactly the same effect, no performance penalty, and is SQL Standard compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't really optimize a *query*. Queries are always rewritten by the optimizer and may give very different results depending on how much data there is, indexes, etc. So if you have a query that is slow, you must look at the execution plan to see what's happening. And if you have a query that is not slow, you shouldn't be optimizing it.

There's nothing wrong with subselects, per se. As Wernfriend Domscheit suggests, this will give you the minimum column_date, which I assume resides in table2.

```
SELECT MIN( b.column_date ) 
  FROM table1 a 
 INNER JOIN table2 b on a.column1 = b.column1 
 WHERE a.id= '1234'
```

That is guaranteed to give you a single row. If you needed more than just the date field, this will select the rows with the minimum date:

```
 SELECT a.*, b.column_date
  FROM table1 a 
 INNER JOIN table2 b on a.column1 = b.column1 
 WHERE a.id= '1234'
   AND b.column_date = ( SELECT MIN( b2.column_date ) FROM table2 b2 )
```

But if your column_date is not unique, this may return multiple rows. If that's possible, you'll need something in the data to differentiate the rows to select. This is guaranteed to give you a single row:

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT a.*, b.column_date
      FROM table1 a 
     INNER JOIN table2 b on a.column1 = b.column1 
     WHERE a.id= '1234'
       AND b.column_date = ( SELECT MIN( b2.column_date ) FROM table2 b2 )
     ORDER BY a.some_other_column 
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

In a recent enough version of Oracle, you can use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` instead of the  `ROWNUM` query. I don't think it makes a difference.